# Kivy button implementation - how can I do that with my written code?

Tags: python, function, button, kivy

I'm newbie in python and kivy programming and to learn a bit more I've tried to make a small music player - it plays sound if I choose from balk list next to the pane - but I can't get that pane itself to work - I  need some explanation how to achieve that and the similair subjects aren't very helpful. I've tried to get exactly 4 buttons in grip layout to work - but without any effect.Here is my code in python\kivy:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from os import listdir, path

Builder.load_file("views/theme.kv")

class Player(Widget):
    directory = "" #directory path;
    currentlyplaying = "" #now playing song;

    def Gettrack_path(self):
        try:
            track = open("path/path.dat", "r")
            self.ids.direct.text = str(track.readline())
            track.close()
            self.ids.searchBtn.text = "Search"
            self.load_tracks()
        except:
           self.ids.direct.text = ''

    def Savetrack_path(self, path):
        track = open("path/path.dat", "w")
        track.write(path)
        track.close()

    def select(self, path):
        self.directory = path
        self.ids.direct.text - self.directory
        self.ids.searchBtn.text = "Search tracks"
        self.Savetrack_path(self.directory)
        self.load_tracks()

    def load_tracks(self):
        tracks = []
        self.directory = self.ids.direct.text
        if not self.directory.endswith("/"):
            self.directory += "/"

        if not path.exists(self.directory):
            self.ids.status.text = "Given path doesn't exist"
            self.ids.status.color = (1,0,0,1)
        else:
            self.ids.status.text = ""
            self.ids.scroll.bind(minimum_height = self.ids.scroll.setter("height"))

        for file in listdir(self.directory):
            if file.endswith(".mp3") or file.endswith(".wav") or file.endswith(".aiff") or file.endswith(".aac") or file.endswith(".ogg") or file.endswith(".mp4") or file.endswith(".wma"):
                tracks.append(file)
        if tracks == [] and self.directory != "":
            self.ids.status.text = "No tracks found"
            self.ids.status.color = (1,0,0,1)
        if self.directory == "/" or self.directory == "":
            try:
                self.ids.status.text = "No tracks found - given path doesn't exist"
                self.ids.status.color = (1,0,0,1)
            except:
                self.ids.status.text ="Error loading path"
                self.ids.status.color = (1,0,0,1)
                self.directory = "/"
        tracks.sort()

        for track in tracks:
            def playTrack(bt):
                try:
                    self.currentlyplaying.stop()
                except:
                    pass
                finally:
                    if track.endswith(".mp3"): 
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.mp3')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text
                    if track.endswith(".wav"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.wav')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text
                    if track.endswith(".aiff"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.aiff')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text
                    if track.endswith(".aac"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.aac')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text
                    if track.endswith(".ogg"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.ogg')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text
                    if track.endswith(".mp4"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.mp4')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text
                    if track.endswith(".wma"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.wma')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text

            btn = Button(text = track[:-4], on_press = playTrack)
            self.ids.scroll.add_widget(btn)
            if tracks.index(track) % 2 == 0:
                btn.background_color = (88, 44, 234, 0.6)
            else:
                btn.background_color = (37, 44, 249, 0.6)
            self.soundplayer(*tracks)
        def soundplayer(sound):
            if self.ids.play.state == "down":
                playsound = SoundLoader.load(sound)
                playsound.play()



class PyPlayer(App):
    def build(self):
        player = Player()
        player.Gettrack_path()
        return player   
PyPlayer().run()
```

And there is .kv file

```
    #:kivy 1.10
<Player>:

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    TextInput:
        id: direct
        pos: 0,root.top-35
        size: (root.width * 0.3),35
        hint_text: 'Browse'

    Button:
        id: searchBtn
        size: (root.width * 0.1),36
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 22
        pos: root.width * 0.3, root.top-35
        on_release: root.load_tracks()

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: (root.width *0.4), root.height - 45
        pos: 0, 0
        GridLayout:
            id: scroll
            cols: 1
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 40

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        pos: (root.width * 0.4), root.height - 135
        size: (root.width * 0.6), 50
        Button:
            id:previous
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Image:
                source: "backward.png"  
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                x: self.parent.x + 10
                size: self.size
        Button:
            id:pause
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Image:
                source: "pause.png"
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                x: self.parent.x + 10
                size: self.size
        Button:
            id:play
            on_press: root.soundplayer()
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Image:
                source: "play.png"
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                x: self.parent.x + 10
                size: self.size

        Button:
            id:forward
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 1

            Image:
                source: "forward.png"
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                x: self.parent.x + 10
                size: self.size
    Button:
        id: nowplay
        text: 'Currently Playing'
        pos: (root.width * 0.4),root.height - 85
        size: (root.width * 0.6), 50
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

    Label:
        id: status
        text: ''
        pos: root.width * 0.15, root.top * 0.5
```

It's my first question here so please guys understand that I don't have experience yet

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. I see you have defined 4 buttons in a `GridLayout`, but only assigned an `on_press` action to one of them. So the three without any action defined will have `no effect`.  Please be clear about what your question is.

Comment: I know that must use on_press at each of those buttons but my problem is to how to write a correct functions to them - my buttons are as follows previous song, pause, play and next song - I thinking myself how to do that but l'm failing badly every try

Comment: So you start by writing a method in `Player` for each of those buttons. Use the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html) for help. For example, the `pause` method would probably call the `stop()` method from `Sound` and maybe the `get_pos()` method if you want `play` to continue from the paused point, The `previous` and `next` methods are simply stopping any currently playing sound and calling `SoundLoader` on the next or previous track. You will probably need your `tracks` list to be an instance variable instead of local to `load_tracks`.

Comment: Thanks John I'll immediately go try your tips into my code - I didn't think about those methods and I was trying to write functions direct into "load_tracks" - I see my mistakes now. Thank you for your time and have nice weekend. I'll let you know when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That took not so long but I forgot to post my code - maybe somebody will learn or reuse my answer in own project:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from os import listdir, path

Builder.load_file("views/theme.kv")

class Player(Widget):
    directory = "" #directory path;
    currentlyplaying = "" #now playing song;
    position = 0
    volume = 0
    maxvolume = NumericProperty(1.0)
    tracks = []
    def Gettrack_path(self):
        try:
            track = open("path/path.dat", "r")
            self.ids.direct.text = str(track.readline())
            track.close()
            self.ids.searchBtn.text = "Search"
            self.load_tracks()
        except:
           self.ids.direct.text = ''

    def Savetrack_path(self, path):
        track = open("path/path.dat", "w")
        track.write(path)
        track.close()

    def load_tracks(self):
        self.directory = self.ids.direct.text
        if not self.directory.endswith("\\"):
            self.directory += "\\"

        if not path.exists(self.directory):
            self.ids.status.text = "Given path doesn't exist"
            self.ids.status.color = (1,0,0,1)
        else:
            self.ids.status.text = ""
            self.ids.scroll.bind(minimum_height = self.ids.scroll.setter("height"))

        for file in listdir(self.directory):
            if file.endswith(".mp3") or file.endswith(".wav") or file.endswith(".aiff") or file.endswith(".aac") or file.endswith(".ogg") or file.endswith(".mp4") or file.endswith(".wma"):
                self.tracks.append(file)
        if self.tracks == [] and self.directory != "":
            self.ids.status.text = "No tracks found"
            self.ids.status.color = (1,0,0,1)
        if self.directory == "\\" or self.directory == "":
            try:
                self.ids.status.text = "No tracks found - given path doesn't exist"
                self.ids.status.color = (1,0,0,1)
            except:
                self.ids.status.text ="Error loading path"
                self.ids.status.color = (1,0,0,1)
                self.directory = "\\"
        self.tracks.sort()
        for track in self.tracks:
            def playTrack(bt):
                try:
                    self.currentlyplaying.stop()
                except:
                    pass
                finally:
                    if track.endswith(".mp3"): 
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.mp3')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text+'.mp3'
                    if track.endswith(".wav"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.wav')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text+'.wav'
                    if track.endswith(".aiff"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.aiff')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text+'.aiff'
                    if track.endswith(".aac"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.aac')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text+'.aac'
                    if track.endswith(".ogg"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.ogg')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text+'.ogg'
                    if track.endswith(".mp4"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.mp4')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text+'.mp4'
                    if track.endswith(".wma"):
                        self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory+bt.text+'.wma')
                        self.currentlyplaying.play()
                        self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                        self.ids.nowplay.text = bt.text+'.wma'

            btn = Button(text = track[:-4], on_press = playTrack)
            self.ids.scroll.add_widget(btn)
            if self.tracks.index(track) % 2 == 0:
                btn.background_color = (88, 44, 234, 0.6)
            else:
                btn.background_color = (37, 44, 249, 0.6)
    def pause(self):
        if self.ids.pause.state == "down":
            if self.currentlyplaying == "":
                pass
            else:
                self.position = self.currentlyplaying.get_pos()
                self.currentlyplaying.stop()
    def play(self):
        if self.ids.play.state == "down":
            if self.currentlyplaying == "":
                pass
            if self.currentlyplaying.state == "stop":
                self.currentlyplaying.play()
                self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                self.currentlyplaying.seek(self.position - 1)
            if self.currentlyplaying.state =="play":
                pass
    def next(self):
        if self.ids.forward.state == "down":
            if self.currentlyplaying == "":
                pass
            i = 0
            while(i < len(self.tracks)):
                if self.currentlyplaying.filename == self.directory + self.tracks[i]:
                    self.currentlyplaying.stop()
                    self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory + self.tracks[i+1])
                    self.ids.nowplay.text = self.tracks[i+1]
                    self.currentlyplaying.play()
                    self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                    break
                elif self.currentlyplaying.filename == self.directory + self.tracks[-1]:
                    self.currentlyplaying.stop()
                    self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory + self.tracks[0])
                    self.ids.nowplay.text = self.tracks[0]
                    self.currentlyplaying.play()
                    self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                    break
                i += 1
    def previous(self):
        if self.ids.previous.state == "down":
            if self.currentlyplaying == "":
                pass
            i = 0
        while(i < len(self.tracks)):
                if self.currentlyplaying.filename == self.directory + self.tracks[i]:
                    self.currentlyplaying.stop()
                    self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory + self.tracks[i-1])
                    self.ids.nowplay.text = self.tracks[i-1]
                    self.currentlyplaying.play()
                    self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                    break
                elif self.currentlyplaying.filename == self.directory + self.tracks[0]:
                    self.currentlyplaying.stop()
                    self.currentlyplaying = SoundLoader.load(self.directory + self.tracks[-1])
                    self.ids.nowplay.text = self.tracks[-1]
                    self.currentlyplaying.play()
                    self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume
                    break
                i += 1

    def volumectrl(self, *args):
        self.volume = int(args[1]) / 100
        if self.volume >= int(self.maxvolume):
            self.volume = int(self.maxvolume)
        self.currentlyplaying.volume = self.volume


class PyPlayer(App):
    def build(self):
        player = Player()
        player.Gettrack_path()
        return player   
PyPlayer().run()
```

And of course a .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10
<Player>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "264727.jpg"


    TextInput:
        id: direct
        pos: 0,root.top-35
        size: (root.width * 0.3),35
        hint_text: 'balk is empty'

    Button:
        id: searchBtn
        size: (root.width * 0.1),36
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 22
        pos: root.width * 0.3, root.top-35
        on_release: root.load_tracks()

    ScrollView:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: (root.width *0.4), root.height - 45
        pos: 0, 0
        GridLayout:
            id: scroll
            cols: 1
            spacing: 10
            size_hint_y: None
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 40

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        pos: (root.width * 0.4), root.height - 135
        size: (root.width * 0.6), 50
        Button:
            id:previous
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            on_press: root.previous()
            Image:
                source: "backward.png"  
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                x: self.parent.x + 10
                size: self.size
        Button:
            id:pause
            on_press: root.pause()
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            Image:
                source: "pause.png"
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                x: self.parent.x + 10
                size: self.size
        Button:
            id:play
            on_press: root.play()
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            Image:
                source: "play.png"
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                x: self.parent.x + 10
                size: self.size

        Button:
            on_press: root.next()  
            id:forward
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            Image:
                source: "forward.png"
                y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height - 75
                x: self.parent.x + 10
                size: self.size
    Slider:
        id:volumecontrol
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        pos: (root.width * 0.4), root.height - 200
        size: (root.width * 0.6) - 15, 50
        max: 100
        min: 0
        on_value:root.volumectrl(*args)

    Button:
        id: nowplay
        text: 'Currently Playing'
        pos: (root.width * 0.4),root.height - 85
        size: (root.width * 0.6), 50
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

    Label:
        id: status
        text: ''
        pos: root.width * 0.15, root.top * 0.5
```

What have I changed - at first I replace a list of my tracks to head class - that makes it available for all functions and make possible to write functions to all buttons in my small interface - I've used in kv file a link to background image what makes it a bit prettier, and as bonus I've written a volume control function and I've created a bar for it to read constantly the value whatever it is in range from 0 to 100